# Timer not working in the python code

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, timeit

The program should respond and print val within the time limit specified by the time variable.

```
import timeit
from threading import Thread

val = 0
time = 3.05274241722e-05

def function1():
    global val
    for i in range(0,10000):
        val = val+i
    return val

def function2():
    global val
    for i in range(0,10000):
        val = val+i
    return val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    Thread(target = function1).start()
    Thread(target = function2).start()
    while time-1 <=(timeit.default_timer() - start_time):
        if time-1 >(timeit.default_timer() - start_time):
            break
        print time-1
        print timeit.default_timer() - start_time
        print val
        pass

    print val
    Thread(target = function1).exit()
    Thread(target = function2).exit()
```

And also please let me know whether I'm using the threads correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

your `time-1` is a negative value, this is going to be ALWAYS smaller than `(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)`, so it's an infinite loop and that `if` statement is even more redundant. Also, the way you use thread is wrong.

try the following code

```
import timeit
from threading import Thread
val = 0
time = 2.38282775879e-05
flag = False

def function1():
    global val
    global flag
    for i in range(0,1000):
        if not flag:
            val = val+i
            print val
        else:
            break

def function2():
    global val
    global flag
    for i in range(0,1000):
        if not flag:
            val = val+i
            print val
        else:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f1 = Thread(target = function1)
    f2 = Thread(target = function2)
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    f1.start()
    f2.start()
    f1.join(time)
    f2.join(time)
    flag = True
    end_time = timeit.default_timer()
    f1.join()
    f2.join()
    if time <= end_time - start_time:
        print "Timeout"
    else:
        print "Finished before timeout"
    print end_time - start_time
    print val
```

Comment: Thank you. but my goal is to run 2 threads in parallel which will generate val using two different methods. The program should return a val within the time specified under time variable which will be set dynamically.

Comment: Also could you please explain f1.join(time) do? because I have not done join this way.. Thank you